# Updating android APK not via play store

Tags: java, android, apk

First of all, I'm sorry I don't speak very good english. I have a thesis project to make android app similiar like logo quiz using java. Basicaly, I have to make the admin site of this app or make it updatable not via play store. I'm going to put the newest APK version in a website host. Does anyone here know how to make it work like that? Or maybe you have another idea to make the admin site? please tell me

Comment: Would it be enough if the user is told that there is a new version of the app on the site ? Or is it required that the update must also be installed ?

Comment: The update also must be installed. The user will check is there any newest version. Then user will download it and the downloaded APK will be automaticaly installed

Comment: I've updated the answer to reflect the new google content policy. You can still allow automatic updates, but not via google play.

Answer (score 2):

> The update also must be installed. The user will check is there any newest version. Then user will download it and the downloaded APK will be automaticaly installed

This is not easy to do. The only option you have is to write some server side code to let a client know what the latest version is. The client can trigger a local notification and alert the user that a new version is available.

Facebook [managed to do](http://www.insidefacebook.com/2013/03/18/silent-updates-for-android-download-latest-version-of-facebook-without-google-play/) what you're asking but I'm sure a lot of engineering effort went into it.

**[EDIT]**

Google has [updated](https://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy.html) their policy to forbid dynamic updates.

> “An app downloaded from Google Play may not modify, replace or update
>   its own APK binary code using any method other than Google Play's
>   update mechanism.”

Comment: This might be out of date (and two years old) but I will have a .txt file with a version number inside it next to the .apk. When I do a background sync, I first check that .txt file contents with a HTTPUrlConnection and if it doesn't match the local copy I download the .apk and then throw up an AlertDialog with the install button. The install button opens a URI intent to the local location of the .apk file.

Comment: You could do that, but installing from sources other than the playstore require that the user approve it. From the perspective of the products experience this is not ideal.

Comment: Not ideal, but if you wrote an app that's not allowed in the Play Store or one for an enterprise that doesn't want to give Google access to the data there's not really many options.

Answer (score 1):

FYI Without uploading on play store, user will never come to know about the updates of your app.

Or

There must be some kind of notification you should implement in your admin and send to your users using the app, and through that notification you should ask user to download updated APK from your web.

Comment: It is a requirement for my thesis project to make it updatable not via play store. 

After the user download the newest APK, will it be automaticaly installed? If it's not, how to make it automaticaly installed?

Comment: You can not make it auto install, but you can provide a prompt to open the file. If the user has Unknown Sources disabled, it will ask you to allow it. Otherwise it will open Android's Installation Intent.